# Sql Count Where Groupby SubQuery

Tags: sql, sqlite

Hey I have this query,

```
SELECT item_type.id, item_type.item_type, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item WHERE item.sale_transaction_id IS NULL) as stock_qty,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item WHERE item.sale_transaction_id IS NOT NULL) as sold_qty
FROM item
JOIN item_type ON item.item_type_id = item_type.id
GROUP BY item.item_type_id
```

This gives me a result:

```
| id | item_type | stock_qty | sold_qty|
----------------------------------------
| 1  | Book      | 12        | 12      |
| 2  | Pencil    | 12        | 12      |
| ........... # etc
```

But this does not work as intended, I need to do it like this to make it work:

```
SELECT item_type.id, item_type.item_type, 
    COUNT(item.purchase_transaction_id) - COUNT(item.sale_transaction_id) as stock_qty,
    COUNT(item.sale_transaction_id) as sold_qty
FROM item
JOIN item_type ON item.item_type_id = item_type.id
GROUP BY item.item_type_id
```

and the result is what I want and this is the **correct/expected** output:

```
| id | item_type | stock_qty | sold_qty|
----------------------------------------
| 1  | Book      | 1         | 0       |
| 2  | Pencil    | 0         | 5       |
| ........... # etc
```

In my Table structure, each item that has `sale_transaction_id` is marked as sold. 
My question is why the first one is not working as intended? and how do I make it to work as 2nd one? Is it actually possible using subquery for this type of query?

Comment: What is your expected output? You first query is giving you the total count of nulls and not null, not depnding on id

Comment: The 2nd query is the one that I'm expecting, I've edited the question to be more clear, I just want to figure out a way to get 2nd result with using `NULL` and `NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add correlation to the subqueries:

```
SELECT item_type.id, item_type.item_type, 
    (SELECT COUNT(item.purchase_transaction_id) - COUNT(item.sale_transaction_id)
     FROM item 
     WHERE item.item_type_id = i.item_type_id) as stock_qty,
    (SELECT COUNT(item.sale_transaction_id) 
     FROM item 
     WHERE item.item_type_id = i.item_type_id ) as sold_qty
FROM item AS i
JOIN item_type ON i.item_type_id = item_type.id
GROUP BY i.item_type_id
```

The subqueries are now correlated: they are executed for each `item_type_id` of the outer query and return results for this exact value each time.

But this seems like an overkill, since you can get the same result applying aggregation in the outer query, just like you do in the second query of your question.

Comment: hmm, I tried your answer but it still gives me the same result as the first query (a.k.a the wrong one) - There is a typo with double `WHERE`. But is there any way I can use `NULL` and `NOT NULL` for this query?

Comment: I can't see how my query returns the same result as the first one of your answer. Can you setup an sqlfiddle demo with some sample data? `COUNT` does not take into account `NULL` values, that's why I have omitted checking against `NULL` in my queries.

Comment: Also I tried removing the `AS i` and it will not work, so I need to have alias for correlate the subquery?

Comment: Yes you need an alias, because there must be a way to discern where field `item_type_id` comes from.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT item_type.id, item_type.item_type, 
SUM(case when item.sale_transaction_id IS NULL then 1 else 0 end) as stock_qty,
SUM(case when item.sale_transaction_id IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0  end) as sold_qty
FROM item
JOIN item_type ON item.item_type_id = item_type.id
GROUP BY item_type.id, item_type.item_type
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: hmm yeah this logic could works also, but I'm more interested in knowing the subquery version. Also when I tested it, it works okay except for item which has `qty` both in `stock_qty` and `sold_qty`, for some reason it just count the total into first column. For example `book | stock_qty = 1 | sold_qty = 1` but in your query it gives me `book | stock_qty = 2 | sold_qty = null`. I have no idea why it behaves like that

Comment: I'm not sure if you used my updated answer (with SUM in front of the CASE statement), it should not return null values. 
Your subquery does not work because it cannot join on the item_type.id and item type

Answer (score 1):

Start from "item_type" table, instead of "item" table and use left join, otherwise you will never get a row in the query result if you not have items from a type.

```
SELECT
    item_type.id,
    item_type.item_type,
    SUM(CASE WHEN item.id IS NOT NULL AND item.sale_transaction_id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS stock_qty,
    SUM(CASE WHEN item.id IS NOT NULL AND item.sale_transaction_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sold_qty
FROM
    item_type
LEFT JOIN
    item
ON
    item.item_type_id = item_type.id
GROUP BY
    item_type.id, item_type.item_type
```

Avoid using subselects. Each subselect you use will be executed for each row and that will slow down performance a lot. You can run explain on both queries (subselect and join version) and you will see what I mean

It will be helpful if you post an example data of initial tables.